# bind $scope in Directives/Controller

Tags: angularjs, scope, controllers

After binded a scope to my Directive/Controller I can't use its own directive anymore, is there something I should fix? I've tried to find an answer but nothing so far..

**ANGULARJS:**

```
return {
        scope: { fullpost:'@' },
        controller: function ($scope, $element) {

            // Edit Btn
            $scope.editbtn = "Edit";
```

the $scope.editbtn doesn't display in the html anymore.

**HTML:**

```
<full-post fullpost="fullpost">
<!-- edit tools -->
<div class='yardtools'>
<button id='edit' ng-click='edit()'><i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o'></i> {{ editbtn }}</button>
<button id='update' class='hidden'><i class='fa fa-wrench'></i> Update</button>
<button id='delete'ng-click='delete()'class='hidden'><i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i> Delete</button>
    </div>
<!-- post -->
<div class='yardman-post' data-post-id=" + id + ">
    <div ym='info'>
        <p>Post id: <em> {{ fullpost.id }}</em>, Posted on: <em>{{ fullpost.date }}</em>, by <em>AUTHOR</em>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div ym='title' contenteditable='false'>{{ fullpost.title }}</div>
    <div ym='body' contenteditable='false'>{{ fullpost.text }}</div>
</div>
</full-post>
```

Comment: could you add more code please with html?

Comment: @pankajparkar, I added the html.

Comment: you mean you want to change button text from directive?

Comment: @pankajparkar yes, it works if I don't define
scope: { fullpost:'@' },

Comment: Your `fullPost` directive has an isolate scope (i.e. not visible to directives/expressions in the parent scope or in the scope of the children). If all of this HTML under `<full-post>` should really be part of the directive, then put that as a template of the directive. You could also transclude it, but without understanding what the scope of responsibility of your directive, I can't say what the right approach is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you to put your inner html of to directive element to move it to some template, though there is option to use `ng-transclude` but at looking at your current html you could use you inner content of directive using template & access that template using `templateUrl`.

**directiveTemplate.html**

```
<div class='yardtools'>
<button id='edit' ng-click='edit()'><i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o'></i> {{ editbtn }}</button>
<button id='update' class='hidden'><i class='fa fa-wrench'></i> Update</button>
<button id='delete'ng-click='delete()'class='hidden'><i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i> Delete</button>
    </div>
<!-- post -->
<div class='yardman-post' data-post-id=" + id + ">
    <div ym='info'>
        <p>Post id: <em> {{ fullpost.id }}</em>, Posted on: <em>{{ fullpost.date }}</em>, by <em>AUTHOR</em>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div ym='title' contenteditable='false'>{{ fullpost.title }}</div>
    <div ym='body' contenteditable='false'>{{ fullpost.text }}</div>
</div>
```

**Directive**

```
return {
    scope: { fullpost:'@' },
    templateUrl: 'directiveTemplate.html'
    controller: function ($scope, $element) {

        // Edit Btn
        $scope.editbtn = "Edit";
     }
 }
```